# I can't generate the log file on MAUI app [SOLVED]

Tags: maui, serilog, .net-8.0, serilog-sinks-file

I use the *serilog-sinks-file* package to copy the logs into a "*.log*" file but it does not generate the directory or the file.

I added this code in "*MauiProgram.cs*" inside a empty MAUI project:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/Test-.log")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Is any configuration missing?

Thank you in advance.

Versions used:

- Serilog.Extensions.Logging 8.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Debug 2.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.File 5.0.0
- net8.0

**UPDATE:**

Solved! My problem was that I wasn't managing the routes properly.

[File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) should be used to retrieve the directory where the application is located: `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory`

Comment: what is the path that you want to save it there ?

Comment: What MAUI App? What OS? What Device?

Comment: You need to specify a path to a writable folder.  You are using a path in the app bundle, which is not writable